# LDAP "simple" User authentication (JNDI - Tomcat) not stable?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, ldap, jndi

I'm new to java LDAP authentication using JNDI. When shearching over internet for tutorials, I found a sample code from fallowing URL,

http://www.javaxt.com/Tutorials/Windows/How_to_Authenticate_Users_with_Active_Directory

I'm creating web app using JavaServlet & JSP.

Just I want is Authenticate users using LDAP.

My server is Apache,Tomcat and I'm using Xampp for that.

***Now the system is authenticating users well using LDAP but some times it will throwing fallowing exception.***

"javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to connect to xxxxxx.com"

***It will remain about an hour, automatically system will again working well.***

can any one tell me what would be the issue?

I have changed the server to GlassFish, but issue is same.

Here my code,

```
 public static LdapContext getConnection (String username, String password,
            String domainName, String serverName) throws NamingException {

        if (domainName == null) {
            try {
                String fqdn = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost()
                        .getCanonicalHostName();
                if (fqdn.split("\\.").length > 1) {
                    domainName = fqdn.substring(fqdn.indexOf(".") + 1);
                }
            } catch (java.net.UnknownHostException e) {
            }
        }

        if (password != null) {
            password = password.trim();
            if (password.length() == 0) {
                password = null;
            }
        }

        Hashtable props = new Hashtable();

        String principalName = username + "@" + domainName;

        props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, principalName);

        if (password != null) {
            props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
        }        

        String ldapURL = "ldap://"
                + ((serverName == null) ? domainName : serverName + "."
                        + domainName) +":389/";             

        String Auth_Metho="simple";      

        props.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,
                Auth_Metho); 
        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapURL);
        props.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout", "0");
        try {           
            return new InitialLdapContext(props, null);
        } catch (javax.naming.CommunicationException e) {
            throw new NamingException("Failed to connect to " + domainName
                    + ((serverName == null) ? "" : " through " + serverName));
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new NamingException("Failed to authenticate " + username
                    + "@" + domainName
                    + ((serverName == null) ? "" : " through " + serverName));
        }
    }

//Then call it as....

String SreverName = "xxxxxx.com";
String userName = "xxxxx";
String password ="xxxxx";

 LdapContext ctx;
        try {
            ctx = ActiveDirectory.getConnection( userName ,
                    password , SreverName);
             ctx.close(); // unameStr, passStr,
             System.out.println("Authenticated!");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the code you're using is suppressing the real exception. What is the `CommunicationException` that is occuring? Given this code, there's no way to know.

```
} catch (javax.naming.CommunicationException e) {
    throw new NamingException("Failed to connect to " + domainName + ((serverName == null) ? "" : " through " + serverName));
```

Step 1 is to fix this so that you at least have more information as to what the real problem is.

Even without this extra information though, the most likely issue is that the LDAP is being brought down so that a backup or reorg can be run. Most companies run multiple LDAPs and bring them down one at a time so that nightly or weekly maintenance can be performed on them. One way to deal with this is to specify multiple LDAP URLs for the `PROVIDER_URL`, the LDAP provider will try each URL until a connection is successfully created.

```
props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://ldap1.domain.com:389 " +
    "ldap://ldap2.domain.com:389 " +
    "ldap://ldap3.domain.com:389");
```

You'll probably need to contact your LDAP administrator to obtain the URLs for each individual LDAP. And while you're at it, ask your admin when they take the LDAPs down for maintenance and correlate that against the connection errors you're seeing.

Alternatively, if your company doesn't have a DNS entry for each separate LDAP and the hostname you're using right now has multiple IP addresses associated with it, you could use `InetAddress` to get all of the IPs and build the `PROVIDER_URL` from them.

```
InetAddress[] addresses = InetAddress.getAllByName(ldapHostname);
String providerUrl = "ldap://" + addresses[0].getHostAddress() + ":389";
for(int i = 1; i < addresses.length; i++){
    providerUrl += " ldap://" + addresses[i].getHostAddress() + ":389";
}
props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerUrl);
```

Comment: Syon,
I'm really appreciate reply and guidance your  have given here,  Yes I realized that ` CommunicationException ` suppressing the real exception. I have contacted the  LDAP administrator, they don't maintain multiple LDAPs.. And also they have DNS for given LDAP. 
I tracked the exact exception came out , Here it is,
`javax.naming.CommunicationException: xxxxxx.com:389 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect]
 at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Unknown Source)
  ...  more ...`
And I have serialized the Hashtable but issue is same.

Comment: And I have set time out as,  `props.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout", "0");` but nothing changed.

Comment: `com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout` only applies to reading data from the LDAP. I believe the setting you want would be `com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout`. I don't believe setting the connect timeout to 0 will make a difference though (but I suppose it's worth a try).

Did you ask your LDAP admin if they're taking the server down for scheduled backups? I still believe this is the most likely explanation, any decent LDAP admin will backup and reorg on a regular basis.

Comment: I got your time out setting explanation, LDAP Admin says nothing such like scheduled in such a frequently. And the confusing thing is there are some systems working fine with LDAP in same network, but they implemented in php.

Comment: The issue is definitely not a Java specific problem, many people use this API without any issue (myself included). The only other thing I can suggest is to work with your LDAP admins and network admins to try and debug the issue while it's occurring (try to telnet to the LDAP from your server during the outage, have your network admins check to see if connections from your server are reaching the LDAP during the outage, etc.)